# Unable to open connection to X11

Tags: r, linux, plot, installation, x11

I encountered the following error message when I ran the command `plot(iris)` on a local machine with **Debian 10**:

```
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  : 
  unable to start device X11cairo
In addition: Warning message:
In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
  unable to open connection to X11 display ''
```

Based on some of the advice on the internet, I have changed the display by issuing the following command in the terminal:

```
$ export DISPLAY=127.0.0.1:7.0
```

In R I issued the command `capabilities()` but it indicated that *X11* is false and *Cairo* is true.

#### Update

After issuing the command `x11()`, the output is as follows:

```
No protocol specified 
Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  :
    unable to start device X11cairo 
In addition: Warning message: 
In X11() : unable to open connection to X11 display '
```

Can any expert help me out here?

Comment: What happens if you try to open the device directly using `x11()`?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, jay.sf. I have posted the output for x11() as advised.

Comment: Looks to me like there is no [X window system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276168/what-is-x11-exactly) installed at all. I would try [installing from Debian](https://wiki.debian.org/Xorg).

Comment: Thanks. I tried installing Xorg as suggested. I encountered another issue. After installation, I issued sudo startx only to encounter a black screen and the system seemed to hang after that.

Comment: I think you should try to get further answers on https://unix.stackexchange.com/